# Need code explanation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript. In my current project I'm using very often this code:

```
$(function() {

    // init fields and constants...
    file_input_1 = document.getElementById("input-1");
    file_input_2 = document.getElementById("input-2");
    [...]

});
```

I know what it does (executes on page load, some kind of file constructor?), but I don't know why it happen.

What is `$` and why my browser executes this code?

Comment: Not the right site to ask this sort of thing. Search for "jQuery" on google.

Comment: Are you using jQuery or some JavaScript library?

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: @Dave now i know it happens cause of jquery, and NOW can I search for it...

Answer (score 2):

`$` is just a name, you can name a variable/function/object like that. `$` is set by jQuery and is an alias to the identifier `jQuery`, which is a function.

jQuery is just coded in a way that if you pass a function as parameter to `$`, it acts the same way as `$(document).ready`

Picture it kind of like this (of course, jQuery is much more complex):

```js
function $(yourFn) {
    yourFn();
}

// Alerts "Executed"
$(function () {
    alert("Executed");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$()` is a reference to `jQuery`. It is convention to import jQuery as `$` for easier calling of jQuery functions.

So that function calls jQuery, and when jQuery finishes loading, it runs the callback (your function).

Here is the documentation for this functionality: [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-callback)

Answer (score 0):

`$` is an identifier which, in that context, is a variable.

It will be defined by some other piece of code (or throw a reference error when you try to call its value as a function).

It often has the jQuery function from the jQuery library assigned to it.